# Page redirect not happening

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have dynamically created images on my index.html page. I want the user to be able to click on them and be redirected to pic_page.html.

The image links on the index.html page look like this:

```
//<a href="http://mysite.com/index.html?bluepart=view&blueimage=29">//
```

My redirect code in .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{IMAGE}  ^bluepart=view&blueimage=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^/index.html$ /pic_page.html [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The redirect does not work. When I scroll down index.html and click an image, the page jumps back to the top of the index.html page.

Test links to pic_page.html such as this work fine:

```
//<a href="http://mysite.com/pic_page.html?bluepart=view&blueimage=23">test</a>//
```

Any idea why the redirect won't work, and just jumps to the top of index.html?

Thanks,
Darrell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Question:** Why don't you use proper link in first place? You could easily avoid all these problems.

2. **Answer to your question:** what `%{IMAGE}` supposed to do? I have no idea what `%{IMAGE}` means -- it is definitely not a standard mod_rewrite variable.

Change it to **`%{QUERY_STRING}`** then rule will work as intended:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^bluepart=view&blueimage=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /pic_page.html [R=301,L]
```

**P.S.**
I do not know why do you use redirect here (301 Permanent Redirect) and therefore I may be wrong, but I would use rewrite (internal redirect) instead of actual redirect (301, external redirect). For this -- replace `[R=301,L]` by `[L]`

Also, because this rule (as you have stated) is placed in .htaccess, no need for leading slash in rewrite pattern `^/index.html$` -- should be just `^index.html$` (that leading slash is required IF rule is placed in Apache config file / virtual host context).

Comment: It now works perfectly, thanks so much for your help. I have fought with this for a week and a half.